# polynomial defined on UFD with irreducibility implying it and its derivative being relatively prime

Tags: complex-analysis, ring-theory

Define:$O_n$ to be the ring of holomorphic functions defined in some neighbourhood of $0\in C^n$.

Define:An element is irreducible if and only if it is not a product of non-units.

It is clear that those non-units in $O_n$ are $f(0)=0$.

Assume $f\in O_n$. WLOG, one can assume f is a Weierstrass polynomial. I cannot see the logic of the following assertion. It is clear that both $f$ and $f'$ are in $O_{n-1}$

Since f is irreducible, f and the first derivative of f are relatively prime in $O_{n-1}$.

How is irreducibility implying relatively prime between $f$ and $f'$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $A$ our UFD.

I guess that by "relatively prime" you mean "have no common factor". In this case, the result is obvious because a non-constant factor of $f$ can only be $f$ itself but $\deg f> \deg f'$.

If by relatively prime you mean $(f,f')$ is the unit ideal in $A[x]$, this is not true for any UFD. For example, take $f(x)=x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then, $(f,f')=(x^2+1,2x)=((x+1)^2, 2)$ is not the unit ideal (not even radical).

Comment: $A=O_n$ which is ring of holomorphic functions around 0. This is clearly a UFD. I am aware UFD may not imply $(f,f')=units$. But how do I know in this case it does?